# C programming for loop start from right hand side

Tags: c, for-loop

I was having some problem when trying to loop thru a string starting from right hand side based on the digit position entered by user. So basically this will be the output of my program:

```
Enter a number: 1234567
Enter the digit position: 3
digitValue1(): 5
```

And here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int num, digit, result;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter the digit position: ");
    scanf("%d", &digit);
    printf("digitValue1(): %d\n", digitValue1(num, digit));
    return 0;
}

int digitValue1(int num, int k)
{
    int result, i;
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", num);
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        if (i == k) {
            result = k;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So from what I did in the `digitValue1()` is I take the int num entered by user and converted it into string and loop thru. However, it started from left hand side. So this is my output:

```
Enter a number: 1234567
Enter the digit position: 3
digitValue1(): 3
```

I was thinking how should I make the loop start from right hand side. I tried to reverse the for loop and it doesn't make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can initialize the loop variable `i` to any starting value you want (for example `len - 1`), use any condition you want (like e.g. `i >= 0`), and instead of using `i++` you can use any expression you want as well (for example `i--`). You might want to update your condition inside the loop as well. Also, once you found the digit, there's no need to continue the loop so you can `break` out of it.

Comment: If you're treating the number as a string, why not read it into a string (array of `char`)?

Comment: That's the reverse for loop I mentioned about. Let's say I entered 1234567, it will became 7654321. And the position is let's say 3. so if reverse it, it will return 3 instead of 5

Comment: @Denise You need to update the condition inside the loop as well. ***And*** maybe change what you return, because right now you will assign `k` (which is `3` in your example) to `result`, and so will always return the digit position you pass to the function, not the actual digit in that position.

Comment: By the way, there's faster ways of doing this, *without* the need of a loop. Think for a while about what you would get if you, for example, would print the character in `str[strlen(str) - k]`.

Comment: Choosing `3` and `5` for your example is confusing, since `3` is the fifth digit from the right and `5` is the third.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm do you have any idea how to modify for the if statement? But then let's say I used the calculation, it is return me with 53. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Any ideas? I am still kinda stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `i` to start at the end. Remember that `strlen()` is a Natural number, so the index of the last character is 1 less.

There are a few other details to note:

- This does not actually reverse the string being scanned; rather it starts scanning from the end (right-side) of the string.
- Since the loop is starting at the end of the string and working towards the front, the stopping condition needs to adjust to look for the `k`th-last character.
- We want the integer value of the result digit to be returned, so we must convert the `char` to an `int`. That's easiest done by subtracting the ascii value for '0' from the result digit.

#### Updated code:

```
int digitValue1(int num, int k)
{
    int result, i;
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", num);
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) { // Loop backwards from end of str
      printf("%d ", i);
      if (len-i == k) {           // Check if we are k from end
          result = str[i] - '0';  // Convert digit char to int
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This remains an exhaustive search... it will continue through the whole string even after finding the `k`th-last element. (Just as your original question did.) You'll want to think about how to optimize that, so it stops looking once the result is identified.

Instead of a loop though, it would be more effective to calculate the index you're looking for:

```
result = str[strlen(str)-k] - '0';
```

Comment: That's the reverse for loop I mentioned about. Let's say I entered 1234567, it will became 7654321. And the position is let's say 3. so if reverse it, it will return 3 instead of 5

Comment: Well, this doesn't actually reverse the string; it searches backwards from the end of the string.

Comment: Alright but then the output is still giving me wrong answer. I supposed to get 5 instead of 3. Is there something wrong with my if statement?

Comment: But for the calculate part, it is returning me with 53. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated - the problem was with the line that pulls `result` from the string representation of the input number.

Comment: Hmm sorry but it's returning me with 52 for the for loop and 53 for the calculation part. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? I am still kinda stuck.

Comment: Yes - that has it. Missed the detail of converting characters back to integers; when you saw `52` that was the ascii value for the returned digit. Also, the stopping condition was being calculated vs the left of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may note a few things in your code to let you avoid future bugs:

- You're using [`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) instead of [`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). This is (*almost*) as dangerous as using the evil [`gets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/).
- You don't do bounds checking (see previous note).
- You use fixed-size arrays for dynamically-sized input (see the two  previous notes).
- `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, **not** an `int` (this can cause **really serious** issues)!

And finally, you appear to not understand the `for` loop. Just remember this: in C(-like) languages, a `for` loop is not *exactly* an iterator over a pseudo-list. In these languages, this:

```
for(initializer; condition; helper) {
    ...
}
```

Is *completely equivalent and shorthand for*:

```
{
    initializer;
    while(condition) {
        ...
        helper;
    }
}
```

Thus, taking all this stuff into account, `digitValue1()` could be reworded as something like this (note that the first `position` is zero):

```
int digitValue1(int num, int position) {
    do {
        int digit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;

        if(position-- == 0)
            return digit;
    } while(num != 0);

    // This shall be understood as an error
    return -1;
}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers, KemyLand.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your for loop from your side as well like following

```
for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) 
 { 
    // your implementation code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are starting from 0 position. If you want to print from right then start from right. For that we need to set initialize value as len and ending with 0.

```
for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) 
{ 

}
```